# pdfium DLL on Android wrapper dll

Tags: android, dll, wrapper, pdfium

it would be possible to use pdfium dll on a project android? there is a way to wrapper this dll to use it in android?what would be the best solution?
I need a way to wrapper pdfium to use it in a project android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody already wrapped the pdfium library to use in Android. Please check https://github.com/mshockwave/PdfiumAndroid.